# spring boot equivalent for .net libraries

Tags: spring-boot

Hi I am new at spring boot and java world.
in .net world I use some libraries
Any suggestions of these equivalent in spring boot and java world

Castle.Windsor(IOC Container)
log4net (logging)
Newtonsoft(Json process)
quartz(Internal schedular)

Answer (score 0):

The Java equivalents are as follows:
Castle.Windsor(IOC Container) -> Spring container
log4net (logging) -> log4j
Newtonsoft(Json process) -> Google Gson
Quartz (Internal scheduler) is used in Java/Spring as well (in fact the .NET equivalent of it is called Quartz.NET),